# scrolltop to a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

After I click a button I do want to hide a panel and also to scrollTop to a specific div:

```
function StartDateEndDateNull() {
    $("#BookingUpdatePageContainer").hide();
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $("#MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate").position().top 
    }, 2000);
}
```

The panel is hided, but still, the scroll is going at the top of the page, like it doesn't find this (rendered) id:  `MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate`.

**Update**: I did try also:

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate').scrollIntoView();
```

.. but same result.

For example, `$("#MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate").focus();` is working, but being a DateTime field after the focus the datePicker appears having its fancy box. I would prefer though to use the `ScrollTop` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use .offset() instead of .position() to get the top position of the element

```
$("#MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate").offset().top
//instead of 
$("#MainContent_UCHouseDetaile_startDate").position().top
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you add a link in the button which href redirect to the anchor/id of your div ?
And then you can add your listener to hide the div.